# NoMethodError: undefined method `substitute_at' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am getting this issue while destroying an object.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `substitute_at' for nil:NilClass
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:135:in `destroy'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:103:in `destroy'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:254:in `block in destroy'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:480:in `_run__348799253__destroy__466331341__callbacks'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_destroy_callbacks'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:254:in `destroy'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:254:in `block in destroy'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:254:in `destroy'
from (irb):1
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@clu2/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

Comment: show your destroy method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, My app's one of association name was connection which is reserved word in active record gem:

See line #135
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb

I changed the association name from connection to something else and everything is fine now.

Comment: Wow. This saved me unknown hours of head-scratching and hair-pulling. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have find It is a rails issue https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/9371. I think it is fixed now. You can update you rails